# background <video> is not showing on IOS devices

Tags: html, css, ios, video, background

Trying to make a video as the background to a websites home page. Noticed that in my local environment (windows) the video always appears no problem, but when testing the local environment on BrowserStack, on any and all IOS devices the blank white background appears, while android and windows are fine.
This is how my video tag is formatted:

```css
.categoryBtns {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(175px, 1fr));
        /* grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(175px, 1fr)); */
        grid-column-gap: 2rem;
        margin: 10% auto auto auto;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    video {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        display: block;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    .circle-button {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
        border-radius: 100%;
        background: #ffffffc2;
        color: #50a249;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: 'Quicksand';
        font-size: 22px;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px #cacaca, 
        inset 0 0 20px #9b9b9b;
        text-align: center;
        height: 190px;
        width: 190px!important;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        place-self: center;
    }
    
    .circle-button:hover, .circle-button:active, .circle-button:focus {
        color: #143156;
        font-size: 24px;
        border: 5px solid #8de086;
        box-shadow: 0 0 50px #50a249, 
        inset 0 0 100px #50a249;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.849);
    }

    .circle-button img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 60%;
        padding: 2rem;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
<section class="homepage-background">
    <video src="https://store-cmzuk2x1pt.mybigcommerce.com/content/background%20video%20ingredi.mp4" autoplay loop muted playsinline="true" disablePictureInPicture="true" type="video/mp4"></video>
    <div class="categoryBtns">
        <a href="https://ingredi.com/bakery/" class="button circle-button"><img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-cmzuk2x1pt/images/stencil/original/image-manager/bakery-white-175x175.png" />Bakery</a>
        <a href="https://ingredi.com/beverage/" class="button circle-button"><img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-cmzuk2x1pt/images/stencil/original/image-manager/beverage-white-175x175.png" />Beverage</a>
        <a href="https://ingredi.com/wine/" class="button circle-button"><img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-cmzuk2x1pt/images/stencil/original/image-manager/wine-white-175x175.png" />Wine</a>
        <a href="https://ingredi.com/beer/" class="button circle-button"><img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-cmzuk2x1pt/images/stencil/original/image-manager/beer-white-175x175.png" />Brewery</a>
        <a href="https://ingredi.com/flavors-fragrances/" class="button circle-button"><img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-cmzuk2x1pt/images/stencil/original/image-manager/flavorsfragrances-white-175x175.png" />Fragrances <br>& Flavors</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

is it an issue with the format of my video? am i missing something in my  tag?

i have not added all the code i am working with on this specific page, only the pertinent info so apologies if there is css listed for classes not shown, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to convert your MP4 file with other codecs?

> iPhone can only recognize the file with .mp4 extension compressed in H.264, MPEG, or HEVC (iPhone 7/7 Plus or later)

Maybe this article could help:
https://www.winxdvd.com/play-video/play-mp4-iphone.htm